# Does elementHandler in jspdf fromHTML support multiple elements?

Tags: jspdf

I am using jspdf to convert an HTML page to PDF using fromHTML(). The HTML page includes multiple images, which I need fromHTML() to ignore in order to generate the PDF.

I want to use the elementHandler to ignore the images. However, I can only get that to work with a single element ID.  Here is the way the documentation shows:

```
var elementHandler = {
     '#ignorePDF': function (element, renderer) {
       return true;
     }
   };
```

I have tried to replace the '#ignorePDF' ID reference to a reference with a class that applies to all of the images:

```
'.ignorePDF'
```

or to include multiple ID's (one for each image):

```
'#ignorPDF1,#ignorePDF2'
```

but neither of those approaches has worked for me. Is there another way to accomplish this?

Comment: I have also tried to create a variable to replace the ID to be ignored. For example:  var ignoreID = '#ignorePDF'; Then in the elementHandler definition, I replaced "#ignorePDF" with ignoreID and this does NOT work.  I feel like I am missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1):

i figured out both issues. To reference multiple items to ignore, set it up like this:

```
var elementHandler = {};
elementHandlers["#img1"] = function...
elementHandlers["#img2"] = function...
```

also best to create a function that you can reuse rather than defining it over and over.

As for the inability to use a variable for the key, that was a dumb javascript error on my part.  The variable name can be used like this:

```
var img1 = "#img1";
elementHandlers[img1] = function...
```

The # character must be included.

It would be useful if the method were modified to permit a class value to be entered so that a single class could be used to denote all items to be ignored.

Comment: Sweet! Make sure you close and post this answer in the issue you created on github as well.

Comment: https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF/issues/714

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore all objects of the same class (called for example `no-print`), as follows:

```
var noprints = document.getElementsByClassName("no-print");
var elementHandler = {};
for (var i=0; i<noprints.length; i++) {
    elementHandler['#'+noprints[i].getAttribute('id')] = function (element, renderer) { return true; }
};
```